# Isaiah 9:6 "Father of the world to come", "Everlasting Father", "Father of eternity" which is more accurate according to textual criticism?

Tags: isaiah, textual-criticism

Isaiah 9:6; Young's Literal Translation;

> 6...Wonderful, Counsellor, Mighty God, **Father of Eternity**, Prince of Peace.

Isaiah 9:6; English Standard Version;

> 6...called[b]
> Wonderful Counselor, Mighty God,
> **Everlasting Father**, Prince of Peace.

Isaiah 9:6; Douay Rheim's Bible;

> 6...called, Wonderful, Counsellor, God the Mighty, **the Father of the world to come,** the Prince of Peace.

According to textual criticism which translation is the most accurate:

- Father of eternity
- Everlasting Father
- Father of the world to come.?

Comment: What does "according to textual criticism" mean?

Comment: @TomasMarkov textual criticism Looks between Original copies of the text and shows which is more accurate, also, which is more accurate translation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word *father* (אב *ab*) — construct state אבי ("father of") — is not so much at issue as much as the word meaning  *futurity, beyond* (עד *od*). "Father," in Semitic culture can mean *originator*, or *source*, or *the first*, or the *progenitor*, etc.

> **Genesis 4:21** And his brother's name was Jubal; he was the *father* of them that play upon the harp and the organs.

עד (*od*) carries the meaning of *until*, *as far as*, *beyond*, *for the remainder* etc.

> **Genesis 8:22** [עד/For/until/for the remainder of] all the days of the earth, seedtime and harvest, cold and hot, summer and winter, day and night, shall not cease.

(The context refers to the post-flood era as safe from nature-shaking changes to the flow of seasons etc.)

So the  Father of (אבי) עד (futurity, beyond, coming, until, yet to come, etc.) means the father of "the world/age to come" (עולם הבא), as such is simply a more poetic rendering of the same. That is, the meaning of  "father of the [what is] beyond" is obvious.

Comment: I think this answer is helpful as well.  +1.

Comment: @SolaGratia very helpful answer, +1, best answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no dispute about the Hebrew text of Isa 9:6, so textual criticism does not help here.

The differences in the OP's versions lies in the different ways the Hebrew word/phrase אֲבִיעַ֖ד (made of two words, father + perpetuity).  This phrase can be legitimately rendered:

- everlasting/eternal father
- father of eternity (this one slightly more literal)

It is the slightly more interpretive translations that give results like, "Father of the future age" (Vulgate & DRB), etc.

The Pulpit commentary observes:

> **Everlasting or Eternal Father**. But here, again, there is a singularity in the idea, which makes the omission of the article unimportant; for how
> could there be more than one Everlasting Father, one Creator,
> Preserver, Protector of mankind who was absolutely eternal?